# Handling zero-argument variadic template in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider the following artificial example:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct A {
  typedef T Type;
};
```

Using `A` with 1 or more arguments works while using it with zero arguments fails as expected:

> error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1 or more)

Is it possible to make `A` handle the case of zero template arguments defining `A::Type` to `int` if there are no arguments and to the first template argument if there are?

Comment: you can just overload f as a function with 0 arguments

Comment: I know, but I'm looking how to do this with a class. f is just an example of using the class.

Comment: I've removed the reference to f to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 17):

First define the primary template as the most general case — which also includes zero argument:

```
template <typename... Args>            //general : 0 or more 
struct A { using Type = int; }
```

Then *partially* specialize it for **1 or more** parameters as:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> //special : 1 or more
struct A<T,Args...>  { using Type = T; }
```

Once you have this specialization, the primary template would be used for zero-argument **only**!

Note that mathematically **1 or more** is a special case of **0 or more** — the latter is a more general case *(not the other way round)*.

Comment: I would be tempted to begin with `template <typename... Args> struct A;`, along with (not replacing) the code you have here. It's something I do with all complex templates. (Still, no criticism of this answer!)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Okay, that would be just a declaration only (which helps sometime, doesn't mean we should always follow it). The primary template in my code is a declaration as well as definition.

Answer (score 10):

You could just add a default to the first argument, no specializations necessary:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T = int, typename... >
struct A {
    using type = T;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<A<>::type, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<A<double, char>::type, double>::value, "");
}
```