# Using std::endl in ostream '<<'-operator overload with variadic template class containing a variant member leads to compiler error

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following code, where I'm defining an ostream `<<`-operator overload for a variadic template argument type `VariantContainer` which contains a `std::variant` and uses the variadic template arguments from VariantContainer for `std::variant`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

template<typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
struct VariantContainer {
    std::variant<VARIANT_TYPES...> var;
};

template<typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VariantContainer<VARIANT_TYPES...>& inst) {
    std::visit([&os](auto&& elem){os<<elem;}, inst.var);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    //If the following line is commented out, a compiler error is raised
    //std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This example compiles on gcc-8, gcc-9 and gcc-10 with --std=c++17 (https://godbolt.org/z/5qvT3f).
But when I enable the `std::cout`-line, I get the following compiler error:

```
In file included from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<>::_S_default_ctor':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1279:11:   required from 'class std::variant<>'
<source>:6:36:   required from 'struct VariantContainer<>'
<source>:17:23:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:286:4: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Nth_type<0>'
  286 |    is_default_constructible_v<typename _Nth_type<0, _Types...>::type>;
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:61:12: note: declaration of 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Nth_type<0>'
   61 |     struct _Nth_type;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant: In instantiation of 'class std::variant<>':
<source>:6:36:   required from 'struct VariantContainer<>'
<source>:17:23:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1298:39: error: static assertion failed: variant must have at least one alternative
 1298 |       static_assert(sizeof...(_Types) > 0,
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/exception:148,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:39,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = void]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1361:2:   required from 'class std::variant<>'
<source>:6:36:   required from 'struct VariantContainer<>'
<source>:17:23:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:2554:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
 2554 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
In file included from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<>::_S_default_ctor':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1279:11:   required from 'class std::variant<>'
<source>:6:36:   required from 'struct VariantContainer<>'
<source>:17:23:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:286:4: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Nth_type<0>'
  286 |    is_default_constructible_v<typename _Nth_type<0, _Types...>::type>;
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:61:12: note: declaration of 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Nth_type<0>'
   61 |     struct _Nth_type;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant: In instantiation of 'class std::variant<>':
<source>:6:36:   required from 'struct VariantContainer<>'
<source>:17:23:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1298:39: error: static assertion failed: variant must have at least one alternative
 1298 |       static_assert(sizeof...(_Types) > 0,
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/exception:148,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:39,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = void]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/variant:1361:2:   required from 'class std::variant<>'
<source>:6:36:   required from 'struct VariantContainer<>'
<source>:17:23:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:2554:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
 2554 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

In my opinion it looks like when the compiler sees std::endl, it is trying to instantiate `VariantContainer` with zero template arguments (which is not allowed, because `std::variant` `static_assert`s this).
But why does the compiler do that and how can I prevent this?

Of course, it's clear to me, that I can create a to_string method in `VariantContainer` to prevent this or provide a more general version of the `std::ostream` `<<`-operator (like `template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const T& ) {...}` and constrain it via `std::enable_if`. But I don't really like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::endl` is a function template, so has overloads.

With

`std::cout << std::endl;`

we have to take (correct) [address of an overloaded function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address).

For this, we have to see between each `operator<<` is there is some which constraint the signature.

There is indeed the ones from [`basic_stream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), in particular

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

(which is the expected best match).

but we also have to check other, in particular, the problematic one:

```
template<typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VariantContainer<VARIANT_TYPES...>& inst);
```

and as `VARIANT_TYPES` would not be deducible from function set, `VARIANT_TYPES` is empty pack.

Now checking if `VariantContainer<>(std::endl)` would force signature of the function, so instantiate `VariantContainer<>` constructors which does hard error due to `std::variant<>`.

Now possible solutions should avoid hard error with

```
template<typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VariantContainer<VARIANT_TYPES...>& inst);
```

- providing (valid or even incomplete) specialization for class `VariantContainer<>`
- Changing primary template to

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts> 
class VariantContainer;
```

(no need to change `operator <<`, as SFINAE will apply to invalid `VariantContainer<>`)

- Changing `operator<<` to

```
template <typename T, typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VariantContainer<T, VARIANT_TYPES...>& inst);
```

Comment: Nice, I got to this part just now in my answer, Why does SFINAE not kick in here? And why is function-to-object conversion even checked?

Comment: @Quimby: Which Substitution should fail, for you?

Comment: Substituting the empty pack in the long function template with `inst`, that leads to a compilation error, why is this not ignored as part of SFINAE? Or does that not count as a substitution? And also why `VariantContainer<>(std::endl)` is this even tried? I mean if I have `foo(int), foo(string)` I do not expect `foo(10)` fail with "`string(10)` leads to an error" message. Why is this case different? Thank you.

Comment: here we have 2 overload resolution, one to know which address of overload to take, and after the one with selected function pointer. we have `foo(&bar)` ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TjzeTM)). which `bar` do we expect, we have to check with all available `foo`, so we instantiate possible `foo`, non deducible pack become empty, non deducible type make the overload rejected. but `VariantContainer<>` is valid from substituion point of view

Comment: Thank you very much, the last sentence clears it up. If I may suggest adding `template<>struct VariantContainer<>;` to the answer. It will solve OP's problem as it makes `VariantContainer<>` invalid, I had this in my answer, but I could not explain the behaviour as you did.

Comment: Making `VariantContainer<>` incomplete or empty or valid in some other way should indeed fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I used the incomplete template specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I have tried to define VariantContainer like this:

```
template<typename VARIANT_TYPE, typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
struct VariantContainer {
    std::variant<VARIANT_TYPE, VARIANT_TYPES...> var;
};
```

just to make sure that there must be given one template argument.

And now it works!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct A{
    int a;
};

struct B{
    int b;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& inst) {os << inst.a; return os;}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const B& inst) {os << inst.b; return os;}

template<typename VARIANT_TYPE, typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
struct VariantContainer {
    std::variant<VARIANT_TYPE, VARIANT_TYPES...> var;
};

template<typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VariantContainer<VARIANT_TYPES...>& inst) {
    std::visit([&os](auto&& elem){os<<elem;}, inst.var);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    VariantContainer<A, B> insta{A{1}};
    VariantContainer<A, B> instb{B{1}};
    std::cout << "If I want to print something, I get a compiler error." << insta << " " << instb<< std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Aaaand alternatively you can change `operator<<` to `template<typename TYPE, typename... VARIANT_TYPES>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VariantContainer<TYPE, VARIANT_TYPES...>& inst) {`. Or with `typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(VARIANT_TYPES), std::ostream&>::type
operator<<(....) { ....}` seems to be fine too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879564/handling-zero-argument-variadic-template-in-c11 ?

Comment: This avoid the problem but doesn't explain it: why that `std::cout` try to instantiate `VariantContainer<>` ?